# selectBooleanCheckbox in a DataTable in ui:repeat

Tags: java, jsf, seam, richfaces

I'm having some problem using multiple selectBooleanCheckBox in multiple DataTables in ui:repeat.

Something like this

```xml
<ui:repeat var="f" value="#{mybean.values}">
    <rich:dataTable value="#{f.values}" var="v">
        <rich:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{mybean.selected[v.id]}"/>
        </rich:column>
    </rich:dataTable>
</ui:repeat>
```

In the backing bean, in the selected map, I found the wrong ids.

Anothery strange behaviour is that when i sort the column using the sortBy attribute, it sorts all the column rendered.

I've found the bug on the jira

[RichFaces JIRA](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/RF-4758)

If I use the

```xml
<c:forEach />
```

tag instead of

```xml
<ui:repeat />
```

Is a little better (no sorting between tables, more values are right in the backing bean), but sometimes it's still wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: What IDs are you getting (ie. is it all the same one)?

Comment: No, it's not. Each row has got a different id. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved ordering the values, since I was binding to a Set.  I've used the SortedSet. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `a4j:repeat`.

I often have problems updating values on the backend using Richfaces from within `ui:repeat` (although normally with `a4j:commandLink/commandButton`).

EDIT: And do you have a well defined equals() and hashcode() for the Class that you are adding to the list/set?

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I've defined it, but the problem is in richfaces, the values in the backing bean are wrong. It is more like a problem with the interation of the Extended Data Model, i think.